# Plot surface graph with 3 lists

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I plot a surface graph with Matplotlib (python), if I only have 3 lists (X, Y, Z)? I would also like to interpolate the rest of the values so that the graph area is completely filled. I've tried through similar answers found here, however, without success.

```
X = [925, 875, 840, 800, 775, 726, 689, 650, 626] #*seconds spent - dependent variable*

Y = [0.9960, 0.9680, 0.9600, 0.9540, 0.9525, 0.9510, 0.9420, 0.9365, 0.9300] #*accuracy - dependent variable*

Z = [600, 575, 550, 525, 500, 475, 450, 425, 400] #*size of dataset - the independent variable.*
```

I tried to use this:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf


x = [925, 875, 840, 800, 775, 726, 689, 650, 626]
y = [0.9960, 0.9680, 0.9600, 0.9540, 0.9525, 0.9510, 0.9420, 0.9365, 0.9300]
z = [600, 575, 550, 525, 500, 475, 450, 425, 400]

xnew = np.asarray(x)
ynew = np.asarray(y)
znew = np.asarray(z)

xi,yi = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(xnew.min(), xnew.max(), 10), np.linspace(ynew.min(), ynew.max(), 10))
    
rbf = Rbf(xnew, ynew, znew, funtion='cubic')
zi = rbf(xi, yi)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(xi,yi,zi,cstride=1,rstride=1,cmap='viridis')
```

And I obtained something like this (not the fully filled surface):

I know that I need to interpolate, but it's not working.

[Surface plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS4S2.png)

Comment: Show what you've done so far, so we can start there and work with that.  Also what similar answers have you tried?

Comment: I tried procedures like in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35259285/plotting-three-lists-as-a-surface-plot-in-python-using-mplot3d

Answer (score 0):

Following [Matplotlib's Gallery](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html), you can use `ax.plot_surface` to plot a 3d surface using matplotlib. Just follow the example in the link.

See also the question here: [surface plots in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170838/surface-plots-in-matplotlib).
Which is the same solution as in the example above.

Comment: Thanks for your attentiton! I already saw this documents, but I need something less sophisticated, principaly, because I have only three lists (I don't have any functions from the data relationship). Can you help me, please?